# Bash Script: Wait Until Google Compute Job Done?

Tags: bash, google-compute-engine

I have a bunch of bash scripts that I run sequentially.  I'm going to consolidate to a single script but there's one part that's a bit tricky.  Specifically, script C launches a Google Compute Engine job and I only want script D (the one immediately following it) to execute once that's done.

Is there a good way of doing this?

In case it helps, my new script would be:

```
source script_A.sh
source script_B.sh
source script_C.sh
**wait until cloud job has finished**
source script_D.sh
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you launch the google compute job?

Comment: If the google compute job is being launched from the command line, you can try to check if the google compute job has returned a 0 exit code in script_C and if it returns a 0 exit code, may be touch a file somewhere and run a while loop inside script_D that watches if the file being touched by script_C exists

A kind of a wrapper cheat around script_c and script_D

Comment: @jeremysprofile using `gcloud` within my bash script

Answer (score 0):

After `gcloud ... &` is called, use `gcloudpid=$!` (I don't think you have to `export`, but it wouldn't hurt) to grab its pid. then your main script will be

```
source script_C.sh
wait $gcloudpid
source script_D.sh
```